# MSVC direct constructor call extension

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-extension, delegating-constructor

In [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23274182/420683), [tloveless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1902313/tloveless) pointed out that it's possible in MSVC to use `this->foo::foo(42);` <strike>for constructor delegation</strike> to directly call a constructor:

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int m;
    foo(int p) : m(p) { std::cout << "foo("<<p<<")\n"; }
    foo()
        : m(0)
    {
        this->foo::foo(42);
        std::cout << "foo(), " << m << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

I was surprised that this even compiles in MSVC; clang++, g++ and me agree it's illegal, e.g. [class.ctor]/2 "Because constructors do not have names, they are
never found during name lookup"

However, MSVC doesn't even emit a warning with `/Wall` and without language extensions `/Za` in MSVC12 Update 1 (2013) and MSVC10 SP1 (2010).

The output is:

```
foo(42)
foo(), 42
```

in both versions. So there's no temporary created, but a constructor called.

**Questions:**

1. What is the name of this extension?
2. Isn't it considered an extension? (`/Za` and the [list of extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) don't seem to think so)
3. Is there some documentation for / official description of this feature?

<sub>(I tagged this question with the [delegating-constructors] tag since it reminds me heavily of this feature)</sub>

---

meta-info: I'm almost sure this question is a duplicate, since this feature is somewhat known. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359241/420683) to a "similar question". Please do not hesitate closing this as a dup if you can find an answer that describes this feature.

Comment: This is not what you're looking for, but you can use the `new (this) foo(42)` to explicitly call a constructor on `this` in a way that will make all compilers happy (though it's very unadvisable).

Comment: @zneak From >=MSVC12 on, I'd use the *actual* C++11 *constructor delegation* feature.

Comment: Yes, of course, and this one is advisable.

Comment: @dyp, to be clear, I commented my thread to show that this use is unwise once you pointed out the conflict - so my "suggestion" is simply that it works in VS, not that it is the best or even a remotely recommended way to do so.

Comment: @tloveless Ok, sry, fixed.

Comment: As noted by Dmytro, this is not delegation. It is explicit construction. C::C() is an archaic syntax for invoking the constructor, before placement new was added to the language (at which point the old syntax was deprecated). MSVC continues to support it for backward compatibility.

Comment: @RaymondChen IMO, your comment answers my questions better than Dmytro's answer. I already knew it is not the C++11 constructor delegation, let me clarify that in the question (as it already is in the title).

Comment: you are welcome to post an answer to your own question. I don't need rep.

Answer (score 1):

It is not constructor delegating. Try following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class C{
public:
    C() { std::cout << "C" << std::endl; }
    ~C() { std::cout << "~C" << std::endl; }
};

struct foo
{
    int m;
    C c;
    foo(int p) : m(p) { std::cout << "foo("<<p<<")\n"; }
    foo()
        : m(0)
    {
        this->foo::foo(42);
        std::cout << "foo(), " << m << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
}
```

According to output field "c" is initialized twice but destroyed only once. As **zneak** noted, It is similar to `new (this) foo(42)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I already knew it is not C++11 constructor delegation. I tried to clarify that in my question.

Comment: I do not think it is a feature. It is rather bug. See, you cannot use `this->foo::foo(args)` because it will initialize object twice. Also you cannot write something like `foo* fooPtr = (foo*) rawMemory; fooPtr->foo::foo(args)` because it does not make sense. `fooPtr` is invalid object instance. `new (fooPtr) foo(args)` makes more sense.

Comment: As [Raymond Chen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/902497/raymond-chen) said [in a comment to my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347437/msvc-direct-constructor-call-extension/23547330?noredirect=1#comment36127858_23347437), `this->foo::foo(42)` seems to be a deprecated ("archaic") syntax for `new ((void*)this) foo(42)`. Both are a bug when used inside the constructor of a class with no preceding `this->~foo()`.